# Can we combine all data types in one?

Tags: c, variables

Can we create a new data type, which will stored another data types such as: integer, char, double? So we can stored anything in variable of this type. If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about C you can use an union :

```
typedef union {
    int    myint;
    double mydouble;
    char mychar;
} u_mydatatype;

// define a new variable
u_mydatatype data;
// access the members according to the type you want to match
data.mychar = '3';
```

Note that all the union members stands in the same memory space (the size of the union is the size of the larger member), so if you assign by example an int to your union, the value will be irrelevant if you use it as a char, so take care of knowing the representation of the value stored in the union when you use it.

Comment: I didn't know about the union, it's almost what I need. But can we avoid pointer? For example: data = '3'. And computer understand that it is 'mychar' in your union. Can we do  this?

Comment: you can avoid pointers if you don't need it of course. Actually there is no usage of pointers in the above example.

Comment: But in C you cannot assign a variable to your union and ignore its type, due to the strong static typing of the language. When you use your union you have to tell what is the type that you are using.
In other languages

Comment: And you now need *another* variable to tell you what type of variable is stored in the `union`.